# Unable to select children (textview) of tableRow programmatically

Tags: android, casting, textview, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to print the value of the TextViews which are inside TableRows, using `TableLayout#getChildAt(i).getChildAt(j)`.

When I try to log it using the above, logcat complains, saying that it's a View object and that it doesn't have the method I'm trying to use (`getText()`).

The only Views in the TableRows are TextViews.

```
// List<TextView> textViewBoxes...

private void createViews() {
    ...

    tblLayout = new TableLayout(this);
    tblRow01 = new TableRow(this);
    ...

    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText("Player " + i);
        textViewBoxes.add(text);
    }

    tblRow01.addView(textViewBoxes.get(0));
    ...

    tblLayout.addView(tblRow01);
    ...

    // Print the contents of the first row's first TextView
    Log.d(TAG, ("row1_tv1: " +
            tblLayout.getChildAt(0).getChildAt(0).getText().toString));

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
TableRow row = (TableRow)tblLayout.getChildAt(0);
TextView textView = (TextView)row.getChildAt(XXX);
// blah blah textView.getText();
```

You can also do it in one line, but it *sometimes* looks ugly:

```
// wtf?
((TextView)((TableRow)tblLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(XXX)).getText();
```

Anyway... what you are doing here is casting the View to the specific type you want. You can do that without problems, since you are completely sure that each `TableLayout's` child is a `TableRow`, and you know that `TableRow's` children on XXX position is a `TextView`.