# onClickListener for TextView in a TableLayout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am fairly new into Android development.
I am arranging a TableLayout, there are dynamically rows generated from data,
each row may contain different number of columns.

Each cell is a TextView object, and I need to catch the click event on each cell.

I've seen a lot of posts here about adding OnClickListener to the TableRow, which ONLY
captures which Row is clicked, not which Cell. 
there is a post here ([Unable to select children (textview) of tableRow programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079164/unable-to-select-children-textview-of-tablerow-programmatically)) which is roughly related, but it is using static column numbers e.g.

```
TableRow row = (TableRow)tblLayout.getChildAt(0);
TextView textView = (TextView)row.getChildAt(XXX);)
```

so my question is do i need to attach a listener for each TextView object, as well as a listener for each TableRow object? how would I do this?

my layout xml is just an empty tablelayout :

```
<TableLayout
  android:id="@+id/table1"  
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:shrinkColumns= "1" 
  android:stretchColumns= "1"/>
```

and pro grammatically create tablerow and textviews from a list of strings.

I know I can use an adapter and GridView, but I need the TextView to be able to span.

Thank you!

Comment: If you need listeners on the `TextViews` then add the listeners only to the `TextViews`.